# Is there any limitation on the number of secondary tiles for windows phone 8.1 created by an App?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, live-tile

I tried to search Microsoft How-to and Guidelines for tiles but I couldn't reach to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pin as many secondary tiles to your Start screen as you like.

Consider the finance (i.e. stock) apps that provide the ability for users to pin each of their stocks to their start screen.

Secondary tiles require user-interactions to apply pins.
You cannot programmatically apply secondary tiles without the user's consent.